# Trigger after insert null values

Tags: trigger

I have a trigger after insert that uses a lookup to another object. However, while debugging the lookup is null. Since I am using after insert, should the field be populated? The field is also required to be filled in so the possibility of it not being filled in on save is not possible.

Code:

```
trigger ImplementingTrigger on Account (after insert) {
    for(Account a : Trigger.New){
        if(a.Type == 'Client Implementing'){
            System.debug(a.Client_Operations_Manager__r.FirstName);
            System.debug(a.id);
            FeedItem notification = new FeedItem();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only immediate fields (perhaps the ID Client_Operations_Manager__c in your case) are populated in triggers; relationships (*__r references) are not. To access fields of related objects you must query them (in bulk).

Comment: Thank you, you should post this as an answer so I can select it as solved @KeithC

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2025/why-is-this-trigger-finding-a-null-value-despite-the-field-being-populated?rq=1

Comment: Made an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only immediate fields (perhaps the ID Client_Operations_Manager__c in your case) are populated in triggers; relationships (*__r references) are not.

To access fields of related objects you must query them (using bulk patterns).